# Maven-dependency management version issue

Tags: maven-3

We are planning to have a parent pom and which has four modules.We are thinking of using dependency management.
There are two versions of Junit and proj1 used 3.6 version and proj2 uses 4.6 for an example.
I would define both on the parent level.
Now when the child module runs.how will it understand that it should use 3.6 or 4.6 correspondingly.
please help.

Regards
Barath

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will go via the following structure:

```
 +-- root (pom.xml)
       +--- proj1 (pom.xml)
       +--- proj2 (pom.xml)
```

If come to the result to create a multi module build which have expressed by saying `four modules` than a situation like you described can be solved in two ways.

First you decide say both module have to use the same dependency and version of it. This can of course sometimes lead to problems or sometimes it's not really solvable.

You can't define both versions of the same artifact in dependencyManagement.

On the other hand you can define one version in depenendencyManagement (with an appropriate version but only one of them for example 4.6). Than a sub module can decide to override that suggestion and explicit define the dependency with a different version (3.6).